# Getting an error while compiling my Android project in Android studio on my Phone which has Jelly Bean

Tags: android

Getting following error while compiling my Android project on Android device in Android Studio:

```
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
 com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
 java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager$OnBackStackChangedListener.class
```

Comment: Have you tried `clean` and build it again?

Comment: try in the termental ./gradlew clean

Comment: i already tried it sir, but it didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the problem you are having. But you can try this.

Once I had the same issue and i replaced
`compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')` with

```
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1"
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1"
compile "com.android.support:design:23.1.1"
```

and it worked fine for me.